# How to reply to "I hope you are well"?

Tags: politeness, email, greetings

How to appropriately respond to someone saying "I hope you are well./?"

There are certain situations in writing where this would obviously not be soliciting a response (requiring a full stop) but other situations where this would be a declarative question (with the associated raised tone, indicated by the question mark); the latter is clearly what I am asking about.

Replies I've thought of:

- I am very well, thanks. How are you?
- I am very well, thanks, and hope you are as well.
- I am very well, thanks. I hope it is the same with you too.
- (Ignore it completely, perhaps in spite of the tone of voice.)

I guess it depends on the relationship with the person, but I would like to answer in all politeness in everyday emails with colleagues/customers.

Comment: Just say thank you.  Even if you are not well, a wish that you are well is worthy of being thanked, and there's no need to break out the medical report.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette.

Comment: It's a phatic expression. It is customary to simply reply that you are fine, and reciprocate the interest in the askee's well-being

Comment: `Thank you I am doing good, I hope you're well.`  Looks good to me

Answer (score 37):

This is very subjective to what message you want to send across.

In a formal setting, you could say *"I am very well, thank you."* If you'd like to inquire about the other person, you could follow that with *"How are you?"* or *"I hope you are well too."*

In an informal setting, you could simply say *"I am."* There is no rule to this. It completely depends on you.